# How to use loop to add 0 to one category if there is no values for this category?

Tags: r, loops, categories

I have two datasets to compare and I wrote a function to compare them

the population dataset is like:

```
                  yes     no     NA
diease or not      1       9      20
```

however, the sample dataset may lack one category like:

```
                       no     NA
diease or not          2      7
```

I wrote a function to try to compare the two datasets and apply them into the whole dataframe that I have, the function that I wrote is as follows:

```
tablFun6 <- function(x){
  tbl6 <- table(x,exclude=NULL)
  res6 <- c(as.vector(round(tbl6,0)),paste0(as.vector(round(prop.table(tbl6)*100,2)),"%"))
  names(res6) <- c("Yes","No","NA","Yes_Perc","No_Perc","NA_Perc")
  res6
}
```

and apply it to the variables in both the population dataset and the sample dataset,

```
dis_popu <- do.call(rbind,lapply(popu[c(154,159,161:166)], 
tablFun6))
dis_samp <- do.call(rbind,lapply(samp[c(154,159,161:166)], 
tablFun6))
```

but the error always happens:

```
  Error in names(res6) <- c("Yes", "No", "NA", "Yes_Perc","No_Perc", 
  "NA_Perc") : 'names' attribute [6] must be the same length as the 
  vector [4]
```

I know it is because I lack one category in the sample dataset and the length of the names that I assign don't match the "table" result but I am quite stuck with how to improve my codes.

I really appreciate any help to help my study more efficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution does not use a loop, so let me know if you really want to and I'll delete my response. I think you'll find that this is much more efficient.

Tell R that `disease_or_not` is a factor, and explicitly list all of the possible levels.

```
> disease_or_not <- factor(c(rep('yes', 5)))
> table(disease_or_not)
disease_or_not
yes 
  5 
> disease_or_not <- factor(c(rep('yes', 5)), levels = c('no', 'yes')) # give the levels directly
> table(disease_or_not) # even though no one has 'no', R puts it in the table
disease_or_not
 no yes 
  0   5
```

Comment: Thanks, @Joseph. but how can I add an extra level, say "yes" with no obs for the variable. The code doesn't work when I try to rep("yes",0) to add it into the existing dataset.

Comment: Thanks Joseph! I have figured it out!